# Update data from one element in RecyclerView using ViewModel and LiveData

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-livedata

I am trying to write an app using a variety of architectural components/concepts and are now at a point where I am not sure what the best/preferred solution to one of my problems is.

I have a fragment inside the app that has a RecyclerView and displays elements from the Database in a List. Each item has a delete and an edit button. Now I have to implement those functionalities, but I am a bit at a loss on how to do this.
I can either update the database and listen for changes there to update the RecyclerView or i can update the RecyclerView first and update the Database when the fragment is destroyed/paused. But I am struggling to implement either of those approaches.

The view needs to be updated when the element has either been changed (display new title etc.) or been removed from the list. If I put the onClickListener inside the ViewHolder, I don't have access to the complete dataset. If I put it inside onCreateViewHolder I don't have access to the item that was clicked. And in OnBindViewHolder I don't have access to the button.

In the onClickListener I either need to change the data the RecycleViewer is displaying (and update the database when the Fragment is destroyed/paused) or directly call the method in the ViewModel that accesses the database. I also don't know how to access the ViewModel and its methods from the Adapter (maybe this shouldn't be done in general) as ViewModelProvider(?)[PlacesViewModel::class.java] needs a ViewModelStoreOwner or a ViewModelStore and I don't really understand either one or how to access them from the Adapter.

What am I missing? What is the best/proper way to do this? It might be something very obvious, but in between all of those new concepts I feel a bit lost. As I said, I am new to Android and only started using most of the concepts here (LiveData, ViewModel etc.). It is possible that I am not using them properly and the whole approach is not correct.

Here is the fragment:

```
class PlacesFragment : Fragment() {

    private var _binding: FragmentPlacesBinding? = null
    private val binding get(): FragmentPlacesBinding = _binding!!
    private lateinit var mViewModel: PlacesViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        mViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this)[PlacesViewModel::class.java]
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        _binding = FragmentPlacesBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

        // set the adapter for the recyclerview to display the list items
        val recyclerView = _binding!!.recyclerViewPlaces
        mViewModel.places.observe(viewLifecycleOwner){ places ->
            recyclerView.adapter = RecyclerViewPlacesAdapter(places)
        }

        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }
}
```

the ViewModel:

```
class PlacesViewModel(app: Application): AndroidViewModel(app) {

    private var _places: MutableLiveData<MutableList<Place>> = MutableLiveData()
    val places get() = _places

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            try{
                val db = AppDatabase.getInstance(getApplication())
                _places.value = db.placeDao().getAll().toMutableList()
            } catch(e: Exception){
                Log.e("Error", e.stackTraceToString())
            }
        }
    }

    fun deletePlace(place: Place){
        viewModelScope.launch {
            try{
                val db = AppDatabase.getInstance(getApplication())
                _places.value?.remove(place)
                //db.placeDao().delete(place)
            } catch(e: Exception){
                Log.e("Error", e.stackTraceToString())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and the adapter:

```
class RecyclerViewPlacesAdapter(private val dataSet: List<Place>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewPlacesAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    class ViewHolder(itemBinding: ListTilePlacesBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemBinding.root) {
        private val placeTitle: TextView = itemBinding.placeTitle
        private val placeAddress: TextView = itemBinding.placeAddress
        var place: Place? = null

        fun setValues(){
            if(place != null){
                placeTitle.text = place!!.title
                placeAddress.text = place!!.address //TODO either address or lat/long
            }
        }

        init {
            // Define click listener for the ViewHolder's View.
            itemBinding.buttonDelete.setOnClickListener { 
                // TODO remove item from dataset and in RecyclerView
            }
            itemBinding.buttonEdit.setOnClickListener {
                // TODO edit item and display changes in RecyclerView
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(
        parent: ViewGroup,
        viewType: Int
    ): ViewHolder {
        val itemBinding = ListTilePlacesBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)

        return ViewHolder(itemBinding)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.place = dataSet[position]
        holder.setValues()
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = dataSet.size
}
```

**UPDATE:**
As @cactustictacs suggested, I added a deleteItem() method to the adapter that removed the item from the dataSet and called notifyItemRemoved to update the View. I also passed the ViewModel to the adapter to call its method. I was not sure before if this is a correct approach to just pass it to another Method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Broadly, the idea is that your `ViewModel` is what the UI layer (the View) talks to. It exposes a data state (e.g. through a `LiveData` object) that your UI `observe`s, and that's what controls what the UI displays. The observer gets some new data -> you display it.

The UI also notifies the VM of user interactions - button presses and the like. So in your case, you have the `deletePlace` function which is basically telling the VM "hey, the user has just decided to delete this, do what you need to do". Because the VM represents the current state, that's what you need to update whenever anything happens (and it internally handles things like persisting that state)

Those are two completely separate paths, isolated from each other. Remember, the UI displays *what the VM tells it to*, so it doesn't need to react to the user hitting a delete button. That just gets forwarded to the VM. *If the VM decides the state has changed* then it will update its `LiveData`, the UI will observe the new data, and **then** it'll update. You're basically treating the VM as the source of truth, and keeping the update logic out of the view layer.

---

This simplifies things a lot, because when your UI just needs to observe some state in the VM, every update is the same. Fragment loaded, populating the list? Observe the `LiveData`, get a result, show it. App restored from background, possibly with a destroyed process? Observe the thing, display whenever an update comes in. User deletes a thing, or updates it? You're observing the data, when a change is stored, it'll update. Etc! Same logic every time. No need to worry about saving state when the fragment is destroyed - all the state is in the VM!

(There could be some exceptions to this, e.g. if a deletion requires a network call, could take some time, but you want the change to happen immediately in the view. But again, that could just be an implementation detail in the VM - it could update its local data state, and let the remote update happen in the background)

---

As far as implementation goes, personally I feel like it's cleaner to have the `ViewHolder` call a method on the `Adapter`, like `deleteItem(index: Int)` or whatever - just because the VH is a UI component, and the adapter is the thing that sits between a data set and the UI that's meant to display it. Feels more like it's the adapter's job to handle "the user clicked delete on this item" etc., if that makes sense. Doesn't hugely matter though.

And it's typical to make the `Adapter` an `inner class` of its parent `Fragment` - that way if the Fragment has a viewmodel reference, the Adapter can just see it. Otherwise you could just pass/set it on the adapter as a property during setup. A `ViewModel` is a shared resource so no worries about passing it around

Comment: Thanks! I edited my post above and explained what I changed. It was not very complicated in the end, but I was not sure if this is actually the correct/intended approach. I was not sure if I could just pass the viewmodel to the adapter like this. Now I realized that it doesn't matter if I access it via the viewmodelprovider in the fragment and pass it to the adapter (which is what i am doing now) or if I try to use the viewmodelprovider in the adapter (which I couldn't figure out how to do)

Comment: @Wckd_Panda yeah let the Fragment handle getting the VM, and pass it to the adapter (or just make it visible to the adapter) - it's all part of your initial setup. The solution you're doing is keeping two sets of state - one in the VM layer, and one in the UI (changing the adapter's internal dataset). This is trickier because you have to maintain both, and update the UI separately for different situations (e.g. delete clicked vs observing new VM data)

Comment: @Wckd_Panda what you have right now *should* be fine (and it was the old way of doing things) but it's not making use of the viewmodel. And for example, if you start using that DAO line instead, the way you have it set up right now means the VM's internal data (in the ``LiveData``) won't update to reflect any change in the database (you're just fetching a list once). That means the VM data and the adapter data are out of sync, and if you lose the UI data (say the activity is destroyed in the background) it will grab the stale VM data (which won't fetch from the DB until the app is restarted)

Comment: @Wckd_Panda basically the "perform actions on VM, observe its data and display any updates" approach I outlined is how we're supposed to be using this whole setup, and it was added to make everything much easier to set up and reason about (and spot any bugs). There are a lot of gotchas with the way Android works, making the UI talk directly to a VM and displaying whatever its state is cuts through all that. Up to you of course! But I'd recommend using that approach - it's the recommended best practice in Jetpack: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/guide#recommended-app-arch

Answer (score 0):

1. create a PlaceListener class

```
class PlaceListener (val clickListener: (p: Place) -> Unit) {
    fun onClick (p: Place) = clickListener (p)
}
```

2. change the adapter

```
class RecyclerViewPlacesAdapter (
private val deleteClickListener: PlaceListener,
 private val updateClickListener: PlaceListener,
): ListAdapter <Place, RecyclerViewPlacesAdapter.ViewHolder> (PlaceDiffCallback ()) {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder (parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerViewPlacesAdapter.ViewHolder {
       return RecyclerViewPlacesAdapter.ViewHolder.from (parent)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder (holder: RecyclerViewPlacesAdapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item = getItem (position)
        return holder.bind (item, deleteClickListener, updateClickListener)
    }

    class ViewHolder private constructor (private val binding: ListTilePlacesBinding):
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder (binding.root) {

        fun bind (item: Place, deleteliCkListener: PlaceListener, updateClickListener: PlaceListener) {
            binding.apply {
                   buttonDelete.setOnClickListener {
                 deleteClickListener.onClick(item)
}
              buttonEdit.setOnClickListener {
           updateClickListener.onClick(item)
}
            }
        }

       companion object {
            fun from (parent: ViewGroup): RecyclerViewPlacesAdapter.ViewHolder {
                val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from (parent.context)
                val binding = ListTilePlacesBinding.inflate (layoutInflater, parent, false)
                return RecyclerViewPlacesAdapter.ViewHolder (binding)
            }
        }
    }

    class PlaceDiffCallback: DiffUtil.ItemCallback <Place> () {
        override fun areItemsTheSame (oldItem: Place, newItem: Place): Boolean {
            return oldItem == newItem
        }
        override fun areContentsTheSame (oldItem: Place, newItem: Place): Boolean {
// example of control of 3 properties
            return (
                    oldItem.property1 == newItem.property1 &&
                            oldItem.property2 == newItem.property2 &&
                            oldItem.property3 == newItem.property3
                    )
        }
    }
}
```

3. in the fragment:

```
 private lateinit var adapter: RecyclerViewPlacesAdapter

// after you initialize the binding
adapter = RecyclerViewPlacesAdapter (
PlaceListener {place -> mViewModel.deletePlace (place)},
PlaceListener {place -> mViewModel.updatePlace (place)},
 )
val recyclerView = _binding!!.recyclerViewPlaces
recyclerView.adapter = adapter
      mViewModel.places.observe (viewLifecycleOwner) {places ->
            adapter.submitList (places)
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged ()
        }
```

If you don't like using adapter.submitList (places) and adapter.notifyDataSetChanged () you can always pass them the list in the constructor (in that case in the adapter constructor you would have the list of Place objects and the 2 placeClickListener objects)

Comment: It calls the ViewModel method, which is great. Thank you for that! But it does not remove the element from the view. Is there anything else missing? I thought if I changed the List inside the MutableLiveData in the ViewModel (replace, remove or add an item), the observer would notify and update the view, but it does not seem to be the case

Comment: there are 2 cases:
1) the element is still present in the list (you see this by placing a breackpoint when you look at the list)
2) you are missing the line 'adapter.notifyDataSetChanged ()' after you submit with the new line

Comment: P.S: If my answer helped you, please remember to mark it as 'useful' by clicking the arrow above